# Why can't mercurial revert some local changes?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

This has been bugging me for some time now. 
I have a Windows 8 VM running in Parallels with tortoisehg 2.9. It happens frequently that mercurial will insist that there are uncommited local changes, even if I haven't changed anything.
I tried "hg revert --all", I tried "hg revert --all -r .", I tried "hg update -c -r .", and still the changes won't go away.
If I open the commit window and check the supposed changes, mercurial thinks the entire file is changed, but to the naked eye there don't seem to be any differences. All the lines look like: 
`-<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` 
`+<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` 
Is this a line ending problem? If so, why doesn't my Windows 7 pc at work ever have this problem? Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this a line ending problem?

It can be this problem most probably - check it with **good** differ, which can show inline changes and switch detection of EOL-style

> If so, why doesn't my Windows 7 pc at work ever have this problem? Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Win7 repository may not have EOL Extension or have different settings (not `=native`) in it

Comment: You put me on the right track :-) I hadn't realized that the eol extension was enabled on my win8 vm (it's not on my work pc). I read about a similar problem here: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/186470/how-do-i-stop-sourcetree-from-changing-line-endings-when-discarding-changes but there it was with SourceTree. I checked to see if the mercurial.ini contained the [encode] **=cleverencode: [decode] **=cleverdecode: tags - it did - deleted them, rebooted, threw away the repo and redownloaded and now everything is normal again :-) thx!